# Dynamically assign a variable depending on window and DOM-element in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, dom

I want assign a variable depending on the DOM-element or window

```js
const layoutContainer = document.querySelector('[data-test-element="layout"]') ?? window
let pageScrollOffsetY = layoutContainer.scrollTop ?? window.pageYOffset
```

but property `scrollTop` exists only in DOM-element and I getting this error:
*TS2551: Property 'scrollTop' does not exist on type 'Element | (Window & typeof globalThis)'. Did you mean 'scrollTo'?   Property 'scrollTop' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'*

Comment: Why are you not taking `layoutContainer.pageYOffset`, since that variable will be `window` if the element is not found? In any case, cast your variable or use an `if` condition to check the type (e.g., `if (typeof layoutContainer === 'HTMLElement') {`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably rewrite it like this:

```
const pageScrollOffsetY = document
  .querySelector('[data-test-element="layout"]')?.scrollTop 
  ?? window.pageYOffset
```

Otherwise, `layoutContainer` might be a `window` if `document.querySelector('[data-test-element="layout"]')` is nullish. And a `windows` does not have a `scrollTop` property leading to a runtime error.

---

```
const layoutContainer = document.querySelector('[data-test-element="layout"]') ?? window
let pageScrollOffsetY = (layoutContainer as Element)?.scrollTop ?? window.pageYOffset
```

Comment: I want to save element in variable because it will be used in the future, but I don't want execute `querySelector()` twice

Comment: @levensta - I edited my answer with another solution.